# Issue with getting current time and current timezone in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have included a php file in my wordpress website. In the php file, I am getting the current time (in my current time zone) like this:

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($time); die(date_default_timezone_get());
```

The date comes correct however the time is wrong and the time zone comes as UTC which is also wrong. Here is the result of var_dump():

```
string(19) "2015-09-21 01:32:24" UTC
```

I have checked all of the posts in stackoverflow regarding getting current time. Some developers have suggested below function if you are using WordPress which I tried and it is still giving the wrong time:

```
$time= current_time('timestamp', true );
```

I appreciate any guidance or solution.

Comment: im sure its right for the timezone the server lives it, what timezone do you want to display?

Comment: When the WordPress is live, it is supposed to get current time of the user's location, so users can be in any part of the world so it is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: `date` is a php function it will always returns the servers time, it does not know what a user is. you need js to get the users time

Comment: Is there any specific JS function that I should use to get the user's current time?

Comment: so you want me to google that for you ok: answer #1 =https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Managed to make it work without js, so what I did is that in any WordPress page that I wanted to get current time, first I get the current location and based on the location I show the time and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your other code, set your desired time zone using

```
date_default_timezone_set ('America/Toronto');
```

See the [list of supported time zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).